# Multiple values against the same tag not scraping

Tags: python, web-scraping, beautifulsoup, python-requests

I'm getting no values for my "Number of Rooms" and "Room" search.

https://www.zoopla.co.uk/property/uprn/906032139/

I can see here that I should be returning something but not getting anything.

Can anyone possibly point me in the right direction of how to solve this? I am not even sure what to search for as it's not erroring. I thought it would put all the data in and then I would need to figure out a way to seperate it. Do I need to maybe scrape it into a dictionary?

```
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup as bs
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd
import matplotlib as plt
import time

headers = {
    "User-Agent": "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/74.0.3729.157 Safari/537.36",
    "Accept-Language": "en-US,en;q=0.5",
    "Referer": "https://google.co.uk",
    "DNT": "1"
}

page = 1
addresses = []
while page != 2:
    url = f"https://www.zoopla.co.uk/house-prices/edinburgh/?pn={page}"
    print(url)
    response = requests.get(url, headers=headers)
    print(response)
    html = response.content
    soup = bs(html, "lxml")
    time.sleep(1)
    for address in soup.find_all("div", class_="c-rgUPM c-rgUPM-pnwXf-hasUprn-true"):
        details = {}
        # Getting the address
        details["Address"] = address.h2.get_text(strip=True)
        # Getting each addresses unique URL
        scotland_house_url = f'https://www.zoopla.co.uk{address.find("a")["href"]}'
        details["URL"] = scotland_house_url
        scotland_house_url_response = requests.get(
            scotland_house_url, headers=headers)
        scotland_house_soup = bs(scotland_house_url_response.content, "lxml")
        # Lists status of the property
        try:
            details["Status"] = [status.get_text(strip=True) for status in scotland_house_soup.find_all(
                "span", class_="css-10o3xac-Tag e164ranr11")]
        except AttributeError:
            details["Status"] = ""
        # Lists the date of the status of the property
        try:
            details["Status Date"] = [status_date.get_text(
                strip=True) for status_date in scotland_house_soup.find_all("p", class_="css-1jq4rzj e164ranr10")]
        except AttributeError:
            details["Status Date"] = ""
        # Lists the value of the property
        try:
            details["Value"] = [value.get_text(strip=True).replace(",", "").replace(
                "£", "") for value in scotland_house_soup.find_all("p", class_="css-1x01gac-Text eczcs4p0")]
        except AttributeError:
            details["Value"] = ""
         # Lists the number of rooms
        try:
            details["Number of Rooms"] = [number_of_rooms.get_text(strip=True) for number_of_rooms in scotland_house_soup.find_all(
                "p", class_="css-82kmy1 e13gx5i3")]
        except AttributeError:
            details["Number of Rooms"] = ""
         # Lists type of room
        try:
            details["Room"] = [room.get_text(strip=True) for room in scotland_house_soup.find_all(
                "span", class_="css-1avcdf2 e13gx5i4")]
        except AttributeError:
            details["Room"] = ""
        addresses.append(details)
    page = page + 1

for address in addresses[:]:
    print(address)
print(response)
```

Comment: you may have the most common problem: page may use `JavaScript` to add/update elements but `BeautifulSoup`/`lxml`, `requests`/`urllib` can't run `JS`. You may need [Selenium](https://selenium-python.readthedocs.io/)  to control real web browser which can run `JS`. OR use (manually) `DevTools` in `Firefox`/`Chrome` (tab `Network`) to see if `JavaScript` reads data from some URL. And try to  use this URL with `requests`. `JS` usually gets `JSON` which can be easy converted to Python dictionary (without `BS`). You can also check if page has (free) `API` for programmers.

Comment: maybe code doesn't show error because you use `try/except` to catch and hide errors. You could `print()` errors to see that there was problem `except AttributeError as ex: print(ex)`

Comment: maybe you should display `response.content` to see what you really get from server. Maybe server sends warning for bots/scripts or captcha. OR maybe server sends  HTML with different classes - it may use different values for different devices or even different users.

Comment: first you could use `print()` to see which part of code is executed and what you really have in variables. It is called `"print debuging"` and it helps to see what code is doing.

Answer (score 1):

Selecting by `class_="css-1avcdf2 e13gx5i4"` seems brittle, the class might change all the time. Try different CSS selector:

```py
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

url = "https://www.zoopla.co.uk/property/uprn/906032139/"
soup = BeautifulSoup(requests.get(url).content, "html.parser")

tag = soup.select_one('#timeline p:has(svg[data-testid="bed"]) + p')

no_beds, beds = tag.get_text(strip=True, separator=" ").split()
print(no_beds, beds)
```

Prints:

```
1 bed
```

---

If you want all types of rooms:

```py
for detail in soup.select("#timeline p:has(svg[data-testid]) + p"):
    n, type_ = detail.get_text(strip=True, separator="|").split("|")
    print(n, type_)
```

Prints:

```
1 bed
1 bath
1 reception
```

Comment: Hey Andrej, Thanks for submitting a solution. Very much appreciated. The problem I am having with your solution is it only works for a static URL. My code is looping through pages to collect data and add it into a CSV for analysis. I've tried to adapt your code but either I can't allow for blank data or nothing is pulling in.